# How to add eternal script tag in Gatsby body ? With conditional rendering of script in body Tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

For Example : -

```
  const country = "USA" 
    import chat = ('./utils/script'); // script can be imported  from a file
     if(country ="USA")   //  used in component conditionally  
{chat}
else
{ console.log("Not USA")}
```

tell me without using html.js or gatsby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many ways of achieving this:

If you need some UI logic, you can do:

```
const IndexPage = () => (
  <div>
    <Helmet>
      {country === "USA" && <script src={withPrefix('./utils/script')} type="text/javascript" />
     }
    </Helmet>

  </div>
)
export default IndexPage
```

More details about `withPrefix` (it may not be needed) helper: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-link/#add-the-path-prefix-to-paths-using-withprefix

You can achieve the same result by using `gatsby-ssr.js` along with `onRenderBody` API with the exposed `setPostBodyComponents` function:

```
export const onRenderBody = ({ setPostBodyComponents }) => {
  if(country ==="USA"){
    setPostBodyComponents([
        <script src='./utils/script' />,
    ])
  }
}
```

More details about `gatsby-ssr.js` and `onRenderBody` API: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr/